# RPI.GPIO in visual studio ISSUE

Tags: visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I can't seem to be able to install the RPi.GPIO library in my visual studio python project. I use pip and easy install and the error is always the same.

```
Installing 'RPi.GPIO'
Searching for RPi.GPIO
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/RPi.GPIO/
Best match: RPi.GPIO 0.5.5
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/R/RPi.GPIO/RPi.GPIO-0.5.5.tar.gz#md5=8cbc1cb0c0f1a4d93bf1efe1a745f1f0
Processing RPi.GPIO-0.5.5.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\jponga~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ior49_\RPi.GPIO-0.5.5\setup.cfg
Running RPi.GPIO-0.5.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\jponga~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ior49_\RPi.GPIO-0.5.5\egg-dist-tmp-whq5_e
py_gpio.c
c:\users\jpongallo\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ior49_\rpi.gpio-0.5.5\source\py_gpio.c(101) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used
c_gpio.c
source/c_gpio.c(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/mman.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
'RPi.GPIO' failed to install. Exit code: 1
```

I tried downloading Cygwin and no hope.
If someone can give me a compiled version of the RPi.GPIO so I can pop the folders in my python2.7 folder that may work.

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: Any update on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

`<sys/mman.h>` is a Unix header and is not available on Windows. You could try the code below but if you have Visual Studio 2012 or above I'm not sure it will work.

https://github.com/witwall/mman-win32